# Issues installing anything after failed AMDGPU driver install

Tags: drivers, dpkg, gpu

Im having some issues since a failed install of the AMD GPU drivers from AMD's website.

I ran the AMDGPU-PRO-INSTALL script and it failed with errors (i am unable to reproduce this at this time)

I used the stack from the following page.

https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20

Now every time i try and install a program using apt install the following is displayed.

```
andrew@andrew-Lenovo-IdeaPad-C340-14API:~$ sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
p7zip-full is already the newest version (16.02+dfsg-7build1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.0.15-1098277) ...
Removing old amdgpu-5.6.0.15-1098277 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.6.0.15-1098277
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.0.15-1098277 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-58-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-58-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms-firmware.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Im not very experienced with Linux and have no idea what is going on here, could anyone help me resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The driver is incompatible with the kernel.